# How to sum incrementaly in Oracle 8?

Tags: oracle, sum

I need to do an incremental sum in Oracle.

My situation is the following:

```
RecordID      Value

1            1
2            2
3            5
4            10
```

And I need to get something like this:

```
RecordID      Sum_incremental

1            (1)
2            (1 + 2)
3            (1 + 2 + 5)
4            (1 + 2 + 5 + 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The clues: self join and group by.

The solution:

```
select a.recordid, sum(b.value) sum_incremental from mytable a, mytable b
where b.recordid <= a.recordid group by a.recordid
```

Comment: Hi, I have tested this solution, but it is not working for me.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Because it should be standard SQL, but I only tested it in an Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 2):

```
select recordid, 
       sum(value) over (order by recordid)
from some_data
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using oracle 8, I don't have the OVER functionality.

Comment: @Andre: According to the manual, this is available in 8.1.7: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A87860_01/doc/index.htm

Comment: That's why specifying a version should always have at least 4 numbers separated by dots ... I don't know exactly in which 8 version analytic functions became available - I've read somewhere it was 8.1.6. What I do know is that it was only available in Enterprise Edition. From version 9 onwards, analytic functions are also available in other editions.